# Powershell: How to incrementally scale up variables in a loop?

Tags: powershell, yaml, powercli

I'm a scripting/PowerShell/PowerCLI novice. I am tasked with figuring out how best to accomplish scaling out some of our existing scripts.

The scripts we have take YAML input from our end users and build out VMware ESXi clusters to their specification. We are trying to expand the scripts so that we can apply different configuration depending on the type of cluster the user specifies in the YAML. We want the end user to be able to expand this out to create as many clusters as needed. All the while applying different configuration based on the type of cluster they input. We also want to be able to easily expand Cluster"X"Type out in the future for other types we eventually define.

YAML input examples:

```
Cluster1: <Name>
Cluster1Type: <Basic, DR, or Replicate>
Cluster2: <Name>
Cluster2Type: <Basic, DR, or Replicate>
```

I know I could do this in a fairly unclean manner of hardcoding a very long if and statement. Something like:

```
If ($Cluster1Type -eq 'DR') {<Code to execute on $Cluster1>}
ElseIf ($Cluster1Type -eq 'Replicate') {<Code to execute on $Cluster1>}
Else {<Code to execute on $Cluster1>}

If ($Cluster2Type -eq 'DR') {<Code to execute on $Cluster2>}
ElseIf ($Cluster2Type -eq 'Replicate') {<Code to execute on $Cluster2>}
Else {<Code to execute on $Cluster2>}
```

I know there has to be a better way to go about this. vSphere 6.5 can have up to 64 clusters per vCenter if I remember right, definitely, don't want to hardcode 64 if else statements every time we need to check what cluster type the end user has assigned to a specific cluster name. I have been looking for a clean solution but my inexperience is making it challenging to find an answer on my own.

I was also thinking it may be possible to use a variable array for the cluster names and then prompt the user executing our PowerShell scripts to input the cluster type for each cluster name they input into the array. I still think there might be an even better way than this though? Possibly a method of running a loop on every ClusterX and ClusterXType variable in an incremental method?

Comment: Switch command: https://ss64.com/ps/switch.html

Comment: Wouldnt this be better handled with a name/value collection like a dictionary

Comment: Read all the lines in with a 3rd party yaml tool. Then do a foreach cluster, write a cluster function that does what needs to be done, inside there use the switch command or your above if statements.  http://dbadailystuff.com/yaml-in-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up instead, creating an array of objects in YAML. Then importing the YAML into our scripts and calling each by Clusters.Name / Clusters.Type. Thanks for the help everyone definitely got me learning various ways to accomplish this task or similar tasks.

Clusters:
 - Name: XXXXX
   Type: XXXXX

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying something like this? 
This is assuming the user is only allowed to enter one cluster type at a time.

```
# Specify the number of cluster nodes to create
$ClusterCount = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the number of guests to create'

# Enter a cluster type to create
$ClusterType = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the type - Basic, DR, Replicate'

1..$ClusterCount | 
ForEach{
    "Working cluster type $ClusterType on new node name Cluster$PSITEM"
    <#
    If ($ClusterType -eq 'DR') {"Code to execute on Cluster$PSItem"}
    ElseIf ($ClusterType -eq 'Replicate') {"Code to execute on Cluster$PSItem"}
    Else {<Code to execute on $Cluster1>}
    #>
}

# Results

Enter the number of guests to create: 3
Enter the type - Basic, DR, Replicate: Basic
Working cluster type Basic on new node name Cluster1
Working cluster type Basic on new node name Cluster2
Working cluster type Basic on new node name Cluster3
```

Comment: That definitely looks helpful for what we are trying to accomplish. We need the cluster names list to be static as it's called in numerous other sections of our script (Cluster1, 1 Cluster2, and so on). I do think how you are suggesting to iterate the cluster name for the if else statement is good and likely will help me. Thanks I will investigate that route a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the New-Variable command to create a Variable that uses another variable for the name

```
$iteration = 1
New-Variable -Name Cluster$iteration
```

This Creates a variable named `$Cluster1`

```
Get-Variable C*

Name          Value
----          ----
Cluster1
```

Comment: I'm trying to be able to apply a set of different commands to $Cluster"X" depending on what the user inputs into the $Cluster"X"Type variable in a way that can scale up to any number of paired variables. I'm not sure if the above answer is applicable to that scenario or maybe I am just misinterpreting this response?

A previous comment above mentioned the switch statement which may help. It will take some study for me to figure out how exactly to implement it in this scenario.